# How to move away from brute force for Knapsack?

Tags: python, knapsack-problem, brute-force

I've been looking into some problems for dynamic programming for my upcoming exam, knapsack seems like a good entry point for developing a solution that is comprehensible at a basic level.

I have a solution that can generate an answer but its not efficient as the runtime is just too high, how can i implement recursion into this?

```
  return knapsack_recursive(profits, weights, capacity, 0)


def knapsack_recursive(profits, weights, capacity, currentIndex):
  if capacity <= 0 or currentIndex >= len(profits):
    return 0

  profit1 = 0
  if weights[currentIndex] <= capacity:
    profit1 = profits[currentIndex] + knapsack_recursive(
      profits, weights, capacity - weights[currentIndex], currentIndex + 1)

  profit2 = knapsack_recursive(profits, weights, capacity, currentIndex + 1)

  return max(profit1, profit2)


def main():
  print(solve_knapsack([1, 6, 10, 16], [1, 2, 3, 5], 7))
  print(solve_knapsack([1, 6, 10, 16], [1, 2, 3, 5], 6))


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Wikipedia: "The decision problem form of the knapsack problem (Can a value of at least V be achieved without exceeding the weight W?) is NP-complete, thus there is no known algorithm both correct and fast (polynomial-time) in all cases."

Accordingly, no algorithm exists that guarantees to find the optimal solution in tractable time. Past a certain size, it cannot be done with current computing capacities.

However, good solutions can be found using heuristics: A good strategy that could be used such as selecting the most valuable items per unit weight, starting first by the largest ones and then filling the gaps with the smaller ones.

Since this problem has been extensively studied, you will find plenty of papers with different algorithms.

Unless you are explicitly tasked to come up with a recursive algorithm just for the sake of it.